# VBScript - RegEx - modify ObjMatch - Pattern = "(\d{2}) (\d{2}) (\d{2})"

Tags: regex, vbscript

This is something I stumbled across while trying to learn a little about Reg Ex.

```
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Dim re, targetString, colMatch, objMatch
Set re = New RegExp
With re
.Pattern = "(\d{2}) (\d{2}) (\d{2}) 0500Z"
.Global = True
.IgnoreCase = True
End With 
targetString = "02 04 14 0500Z Joe is eating a sandwich"

Set colMatch = re.Execute(targetString)
For each objMatch  in colMatch
WScript.echo objMatch

date1 = objRegEx.Replace(objMatch, "(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})")
Wscript.Echo date1
```

ISSUE: I need to find the date which shows up like this "02 04 14 0500Z" and then assign it to a variable in the form "020414".

When I try to replace the Obj match and reformat the date it doesn't work, instead showing the exact text in brackets.

I referenced:
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/24/Regular-Expressions-and-VBScript
http://wiki.mcneel.com/developer/scriptsamples/regexpobject

Comment: You mean it's showing `"(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})"`? I'm a little unclear which brackets you mean.

Comment: @I'L'I Yes, exactly.  It's showing whatever is in quotation marks exactly as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refer to content captured by capturing group, use `$n` in the replacement string (where n is a number):

```
date1 = re.Replace(objMatch, "$1$2$3")
```

To identify the number of a capturing group, count the number of opening parentheses `(` that belongs to a capturing group up to the capturing group you want to refer to:

```
(\d{2}) (\d{2}) (\d{2}) 0500Z
^       ^       ^
1       2       3
```

---

A more complicated example:

```
((a(?:k)*)(b(c)(?:d)*))
^^        ^ ^
12        3 4
```

`(?:pattern)` is a non-capturing group, so it doesn't count.

Comment: I actually did exactly that and it didn't work which is what prompted the question. 

    date1 = objRegEx.Replace(objMatch, "$1$2$3")  
    Wscript.Echo date1 'gives: $1$2$302 04 14 0500Z

Comment: @Adrian: How about `re.Replace` instead of `objRegEx`?

Comment: That worked.  Hmm, I'm not 100% why ObjRegEx didn't though.  Thank you.

Comment: @Adrian: Modified. It is most likely because `re` has the pattern set up an all.